# Trying to wrap a form within a JPEG image on HTML site

Tags: html, css, forms

I currently have a website up and running: http://reinhartasmimenumentions.com/

I am trying to wrap a form around the picture so it would look something like

[image]

Currently I can only figure out how to add the form below the picture.

What do I need to do to place the form to the right of it instead of at the bottom?

Comment: Maybe try `float: left`? But could you post some code here.

Comment: You need to learn HTML and CSS...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the margin properties of the elements. 
Something like this:

```
 <div style="margin-left:200px; margin-top:200px;>
<form>
....
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: The form I have is not an image its going to be text. Customers will enter their information in and then submit. Can I still use this code and enter in my form text instead of an image?

Comment: Sure, I'm just adding a div as a wrapper. Anything you put inside the div will be "moved" 200px to the right and 200px towards the bottom. If you have more divs you probably will need to rearrange the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would break that image up into 2 parts. One part would be the top part(header) and the other would be the lower left section. Then set up 3 divs, the top div contains the header image the floated left div below that contains the other part of the image and then the right div contains the form HTML.

Of course, it would be much better to recreate that image using HTML as much as possible.